# Correct formulation for getting the F-test, p-value

Tags: r, p-value, normality-assumption, degrees-of-freedom, f-test

I am reviewing some code that is used to calculate the efficiency of the elecitrical distribution companies in Denmark. In short, this method measures all the companies up against each other, and then "judge" the poorly performing companies based on the best performing companies. Therefore, a part of the code seeks to remove the companies that have a significant effect on the scores of the other companies. One of the ways they chose identify to identify these, is with an F test and check whether there is a significant change to other companies.

Below is the code that identify these significant companies. My concerns are:

**1:** I assume the pf function is supposed to give me the p value of the observation, shouldn't the first argument be: **sum((mean(A)-A)^2) / sum((mean(B)-B)^2)** and not **sum((1-A)^2) / sum((1-B)^2)**

**2:** Since the for loop is removing a firm from the data shouldn't the degrees of freedom be specified as **dim(x)[1]-2**, rather than **dim(x)[1]-1**

**3:** According to shapiro.test() the data, doesnt appear to be normally distributed, so can we even use an f-test?

```
x <- data[ omkostninger ]
y <- data[ modelydelser ]

F_test <- NULL
for (i in 1:dim( x )[1]) { 
  A <- dea( x[ -i , ] , y[ -i , ] , ORIENTATION="in" , RTS="crs" )$eff
  B <- dea( x , y , ORIENTATION="in" , RTS="crs" )$eff[ -i ]
  C <-  pf( sum((1-A)^2) / sum((1-B)^2) , dim(x)[1]-1 , dim(x)[1]-1 )
  F_test <- rbind( F_test , C ) }
```

To recap, i would think this is the correct specification of C:

```
C <-  pf( sum((mean(A)-A)^2) / sum((mean(B)-B)^2) , dim(x)[1]-2 , dim(x)[1]-2 )
```

Obviously the values A, and B will change a little during the loop, but here is a paste of the last round:

```
> A
 [1] 0.8035371 0.9462844 1.0000000 0.9640125 0.8787025 0.6221689 0.6532625 0.9207995 0.4930306 0.9681518 0.9277190 1.0000000 0.7786406
[14] 0.9769038 0.7501375 0.8107398 0.9012403 0.9512337 0.7622860 0.7455159 1.0000000 1.0000000 0.9880665 1.0000000 0.7981218 0.9608122
[27] 1.0000000 1.0000000

> B
        1         2         3         4         5         6         7        12        13        14        15        16        17        19 
0.8035371 0.9462844 1.0000000 0.9640125 0.8787025 0.6221689 0.6532625 0.9207995 0.4930306 0.9681518 0.9277190 1.0000000 0.7786406 0.9769038 
       20        21        22        23        24        25        26        27        28        30        31        32        33        37 
0.7501375 0.8107398 0.9012403 0.9512337 0.7622860 0.7455159 1.0000000 1.0000000 0.9880665 1.0000000 0.7981218 0.9608122 1.0000000 1.0000000
```

And here is shapiro tests.

````
> shapiro.test(A)

    Shapiro-Wilk normality test

data:  A
W = 0.84079, p-value = 0.0006127

> shapiro.test(B)

    Shapiro-Wilk normality test

data:  B
W = 0.84079, p-value = 0.0006127
```
````

Comment: Because this is a poor approach to identifying and treating outliers (it is arbitrary, not robust, confuses statistical significance with practical importance, and abuses significance testing principles), consider asking instead about how to detect these outliers rather than how to patch up the code.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It is the regulatory agencies that have responibility for making code, and not something that I have authority to change. However, if there are concrete mistakes in the code, that should of course be adressed. 

To my knowledge, this model has been developed with experts in the field and then implemented by a coder. I am unsure, however, how the job was specified by the experts as either: " test for significance" or do a "f-test", so you could be right. How would you detect the companies whose effeciency scores has the highest negative effect on the others?

Comment: Also, if you do you have a comment on the implementation, even though it might not be the optimal solution.  Please weigh in.

Comment: Removing companies one at a time to gauge their effects is a *sensitivity analysis.*  Some of the problems in this application are (1) p-values are not an appropriate way to gauge the effect: you should be looking at a meaningful measure of the difference; (2) you need to consider sensitivity to removing *groups* of companies rather than one at a time; (3) automatic identification and removal of outliers usually throws away some of the most useful information in the data and can greatly skew the results; and (4) there are much better solutions to the actual problem, based on robust statistics.